# Blender 2.92 Fluid / Gas simulation not working

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I'm using Blender 2.92.

Now I'm trying to simulate some fluids and gases, but it seems that I'm not ready for these. I've succeeded setting a simple fluid scene (just a cube domain and a cube inflow), it works ok. But whenever I try to change anything, the simulation just stops moving. E.g. I moved an object after viewing the whole animation and the simulation does not update (no matter how many times I click bake data and bake mesh).

The same thing with gases. I added a quick smoke effect to a cylinder, it worked fine. I added some new objects, set them to be effectors, set the simulation to be modular and clicked bake. After some seconds I press play - nothing changes. Just a black unmoving cloud around the cylinder (picture below).

[image: watdefok]

I had the same problems on 2.90 version and struggled much. I've found plenty of fluid and gases tutorials where people just click all the buttons I clicked and boom - they get it to work. What am I doing wrong? How can I vew the result after changing something in the scene?

Or do I have to set everything beforehand and delete gas domain every time?..

Comment: I'm brand new to this, but you'll need to keep in mind that you typically have at least two objects involved in a smoke or liquid simulation: an emitter and then the smoke-domain or liquid-domain.

Comment: Yes, I used the domain and the emitter. The domain type is selected properly (fluid for fluid simulation and gas for smoke simulation)

Comment: What I mean to say is that if you are moving one object involved in a simulation, you may need to also move the other object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you baked the simulation, you first have to delete the bake and then bake it again after your movement.

[image]

Comment: I do this every time I try to re-bake the simulation

Comment: Ok,then please provide your blend file

Comment: [Here you are](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RUQ1I79yE7fVf2Am_ee1HnfBM-__Ki_l/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: i tested your file and add effector. works fine. my proposal: make a video from the start so we see EVERYTHING what you are doing. So we can help you. Or describe in detail every single step you made. Normally a video is more clear and quicker.

Comment: I don't know what I made wrong in the previous attempt, but it worked fine. I did not use quick smoke effect, but instead set all the properties manually. Thanks for your help, but I'll probably delete the question...